# Can I somehow apply incremental values in groups, in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

If I have a large dataframe in Pandas, let's say **df**:

```
item_serial_number, barcode
12312313-123123123  ABC
12312313-123123124  ABC
...
44312313-123123125  DEF
55512313-123123126  DEF
```

This df lists devices that have different physical sizes. So a different *amount* of each kind of device ABC or DEF fits into its kind of box.

I have a list how many of which kind of devices fit into their boxes, in a dataframe bf:

```
barcode, items_per_box
ABC   3
DEF   2
...
```

I need to assign each device to a numbered box, packing them according to their size.
So every three ABC items should go into same box number, next ones into next box number, etc. Every 2 DEF items should go into same box number, etc.

So the end result should be:

```
item_serial_number, barcode, box_number
12312313-123123123  ABC   1
12312313-123123124  ABC   1
12312313-123123128  ABC   1
12312313-123123121  ABC   2
12312313-123123101  ABC   2
12312313-123123121  ABC   2
12312313-123123125  ABC   3
...
44312313-123123125  DEF   1
55512313-123123126  DEF   1
12312313-123125123  DEF   2
12312313-123126124  DEF   2
12312313-123127123  DEF   3
12312313-123128124  DEF   3
```

Currently I have a for loop going through barcodes of boxf and applying each number by another loop through df.

Is it possible to do it elegantly with pandas .apply or similar functions, or am I stuck with some for loops looping over each barcode? I looked around here on SO, but perhaps I can't think of correctly wording the problem, as I found no duplicates of this question.

Comment: `map`, `merge`...

Comment: I do not clearly understand what you are trying to do. Why is the last row of ABCs in your desired output go in box 3 and not box 2 ? Is your case that only ABCs go in any box ... no mixing of ABCs with DEFs ?

Comment: @bici-sancta I am trying to assign a box to each of my appliances, which are listed in my df. Based on how many of which kind of appliances fit in a box.

Comment: @bici-sancta I have reworded the question, hopefully it is better understandable now.

Comment: @bici-sancta and i am sorry the last row of ABC was a mistake. and no, each kind of item goes into its own kind of box. updated that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
df['box_number'] = df.groupby('barcode').cumcount().floordiv(df['barcode'].map(bf.set_index('barcode')['items_per_box'].to_dict()),axis=0).add(1)
```

Comment: I get error TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable in -> 2158             new_values = map_f(values, arg)

Comment: I edited the answer, see if that fixes it.